# Magento2: creating custom search REST API

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, rest-api, magento-2.0.7

I have created many Api's (both GET and POST) but now I want to create the custom search API with different URL Structure (all the params after ?).

I can create the search API in below URL formate..

**/V1/getSearch/vendor/:vendArea/type/:typeId**

but I want to achieve the same with below given formate..

**/V1/getSearch/?vendor=bangalore&type=2**

Any body have idea to get this formate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally achieved this..

there is nothing special we need to define in XML or Interface we simply need construct the instance of **`Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`** into the class where we are making our method.

for example:

> function __construct(
>    Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request)
>   {
>
> ```
>  $this->_request                 = $request;
> ```
>
> }
>
> public function getParam(){
>
> ```
>  $filter = $this->_request->getParam('filter');
> ```
>
> }

now filter will have the filter parameter value you passed in the API URL..

Hope this will help.

Comment: can you post complete code.

Comment: @AlokSingh in your API method you can get do the above thing, alternatively you can use `RequestInterface` to ge the above data.