# Magento 2: Problem Creating the custom Search REST API URL?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento-2.0.7, api-filter

I want achieve this kind of url in my custom REST API, Any Suggestion?

**http://localhost/rest/V1/products?name=mujassam&value=5**

Before Also I asked same question

[Magento2: creating custom search REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148965/magento2-creating-custom-search-rest-api)